# OpenCV Gabor filtering producing different results than Matlab code with same exact kernel

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

I've created a Gabor filter with the following code:

```
Mat gabor(double sigma, double theta) {

  int nstds = 3;
  int kernel_size = nstds * sigma * 2 - 1;

  if(!kernel_size % 2) {
    kernel_size++;
  }

  int hks = (kernel_size - 1) / 2;

  theta = theta * CV_PI / 180;
  sigma = sigma;

  double x_theta;
  double y_theta;
  double gamma = 1;
  double del_phi = 0.8;
  double v = sqrt(2 * log(2)) * ((pow(2, del_phi) + 1) / (pow(2, del_phi) - 1));
  double psi = -exp(-0.5 * pow(v, 2));
  double fs = (1 / (CV_PI * sigma)) * sqrt(0.5 * log(2)) * ((pow(2, del_phi) + 1) / (pow(2, del_phi) - 1));
  double lambda = 1 / fs;
  double p = gamma / (2 * CV_PI * pow(sigma, 2));

  Mat kernel(kernel_size, kernel_size, CV_32F);

  for(int y = -hks; y <= hks; y++) {
    for(int x = -hks; x <= hks; x++) {

      x_theta = x * cos(theta) + y * sin(theta);
      y_theta = -x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);

      kernel.at<float>(hks+y, hks+x) = 
        (float)
          exp(-0.5 * (pow(x_theta, 2.0) + pow(y_theta, 2.0)) / pow(sigma, 2.0)) * 
          cos(2.0 * CV_PI * x_theta / lambda + psi);
    }
  }

  return kernel;
}
```

The code above creates a Gabor kernel that is identical to my kernel created in Matlab. I apply the Gabor filter with the `conv2` function in Matlab and `filter2D` in OpenCV. I understand that `filter2D` isn't strictly convolution, but when I flip the kernels and change the anchor, etc, nothing helps. The Matlab output looks good but the OpenCV output looks bad. Why?

Matlab (Good):

[image]

OpenCV (Bad):

[image]

I'm using `filter2D(preproc, filtered, CV_64FC1, kernel);` to produce the OpenCV output. How come the OpenCV looks all zebra-stripy and the Matlab looks like what I want? Again, the kernel Mat values are exactly the same (I ported the OpenCV kernel into Matlab and compared and they are 99.99% similar).

Matlab code:

```
img = imread('preproc.jpg');
gamma = 1;
delta_phi = 0.8;
v = sqrt(2 .* log(2)) .* ((2 .^ delta_phi + 1) ./ (2 .^ delta_phi - 1));
psi = -exp(-0.5 .* v .^ 2);
sigma = 6;
fs = (1 ./ sigma) .* (1 ./ pi) .* sqrt(log(2) ./ 2) .* ((2 .^ delta_phi + 1) ./ (2 .^ delta_phi - 1));
lambda = 1 ./ fs;
thetas = linspace(0,pi,8);
theta = thetas(2);
Gsk = gabor_filter(sigma,theta,lambda,psi,gamma);
Fsk = conv2(double(img), Gsk, 'same');
```

The `Gsk` is the gabor kernel, which again, is identical to the kernel created in my OpenCV code.

Comment: Where's your MATLAB code?

Comment: You are correct in that `filter2D` doesn't perform convolution - it performs correlation.  Are you sure you flipped the kernel correctly?  You need to do a 180 degree rotation on the kernel, or you need to mirror reflect the rows of the kernel, then the columns.  For example, if you had a mask that was `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`, the flipped kernel would be `[9 8 7; 6 5 4; 3 2 1]`.  This is the flipped kernel that you would supply to `filter2D`.  It could also be due to the data types as well.  You may need to do some normalization in intensities for the OpenCV image.

Comment: @rayryeng I think I've implemented convolution correctly, but the OpenCV output still looks weird. The gabor kernel is symmetic so flipping it horizontally and then flipping it vertically results in the same exact kernel. I added `normalize(filtered, filtered, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);` after performing convolution, but I'm not sure this is the correct approach for normalizing intensities. I've represented the original image as CV_64F because Matlab is a double.

Comment: Right, I misread.  I didn't see it was a Gabor filter (d'oh), so yes it's symmetric so flipping shouldn't matter.  For the normalization, it's one way of doing it, but it depends on what application your output is for in the end.  Did you try printing out the output values for each of MATLAB and OpenCV and seeing if they match?  We know the kernels match, but what about the actual values themselves?  Ignore trying to display the values - print out the actual output values and see if they're the same.  If they're the same, then it's just a display issue.